# Adapter doesn't load my Room db list

Tags: android, sqlite, adapter, android-room

I was following some guide and tweaking variable name to fit my own project. My problem was most people dont appears to load from Room db into an adapter so when trying to do upon opening the apps my view appears empty. while i checked the DB using DB browser for SQLite i can see my db contain 7 items.

Main activity

```
package com.example.android.budgetproject

import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import com.example.android.budgetproject.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.android.budgetproject.popUp.DepenseDetails
import com.example.android.budgetproject.popUp.NewBudget


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, BudgetVM.NewButtonClick {
    lateinit var budget : SharedPreferences
    var budgetTotal: String? = null
    val vm = BudgetVM()
    lateinit var db: RoomDatabase
    lateinit var adapter: TransactionAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.vm = vm

        //Get the Total Budget in the shared pref and display it
        budget = getSharedPreferences("Budget", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        budget.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
        budgetTotal = budget.getString("BudgetTotal", null)
        adapter = TransactionAdapter()
        //Open Dialog if new user.
        if(budgetTotal == null) {
            NewBudget.createPopUp(this)
        } else {
            vm.budgetTotal.set(budgetTotal)
        }
        vm.listener = this
        //Room
        db = MyDatabase.getInstance()
        //Adapter
        val handler = Handler()
        Thread({
            val transactionFromDb = MyDatabase.mInstance?.transactionDao()?.getAllTransaction()
            handler.post({
                if (transactionFromDb != null) adapter.addTransaction(transactionFromDb)
            })
        }).start()
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

    override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences?, key: String?) {
        vm.budgetTotal.set(budgetTotal)
    }

    override fun newTransactionClicked(){
        DepenseDetails.createTransaction(this)
    }
}
```

The Dao:

```
package com.example.android.budgetproject


import android.arch.persistence.room.*
import com.example.android.budgetproject.Transaction
import android.arch.persistence.room.Delete
import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao

@Dao
interface TransactionDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM `transaction`")
    fun getAllTransaction(): List<Transaction>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM `transaction` where uid IN (:transactionId)")
    fun findTransactionById(transactionId: IntArray): List<Transaction>

    @Insert(onConflict = 1)
    fun insertTransaction(transaction: Transaction)

    @Delete
    fun deleteTransaction(transaction: Transaction)
}
```

The Adapter:

```
package com.example.android.budgetproject

import android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.row_depense_fragment.view.*

/**
 * Created by olivier on 2018-03-13.
 */

class TransactionAdapter(private val clickListener: ButtonClick? = null):
        ListAdapter<Transaction, TransactionAdapter.ViewHolder>(TransactionDiffCallback()) {

    interface ButtonClick{
        fun clicked(id: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_depense_fragment, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        fun bind(transaction: Transaction){
            itemView.tv_depense_description.text = transaction.description
            itemView.tv_depense.text = transaction.depense
            itemView.tv_depense_date.text = transaction.date
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
               clickListener?.clicked(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }

    private var transactionList = ArrayList<Transaction>()

    fun addTransaction(list: List<Transaction>){
        transactionList.clear()
        transactionList.addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

And the util i use to create DB item.

```
package com.example.android.budgetproject

import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.widget.Toast

class TransactionCreation {

    fun transactionCreation(depense: String, description: String, date: String){
        val newTransaction = Transaction(depense, description, date)
        val db = MyDatabase

        object : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {
                db.getInstance().transactionDao().insertTransaction(newTransaction)
                return null
            }

            override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
                super.onPostExecute(result)
                Toast.makeText(BudgetApplication.getContext(), "Transaction saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            }
        }.execute()
    }
}
```

Here's also a link to the project github should be up to date.

https://github.com/OlivierLabelle/BudgetProject

Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 0):

Set `notifyDataSetChanged` within the thread in your `MainActivity` via the handler.